# MacBook Pro Crash when trying to run python's turtle module

Tags: python, macos

I tried to execute a python program via terminal, and it restarted my MacBook.

And I tried to find out what the cause was, so I executed Python programs, and this is the result;

- It restarts only when the program involves turtle module in Python
- It only restarts when I execute it in terminal via     the Python ().py command,
- It doesn't restart when executed in [IDLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE)
- It sometimes makes the screen smaller (which I can't reproduce any more, and seemed very random) (Ask me if you want more detail)
- I'm on [macOS v10.15.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina) (Catalina)
- I'm using [Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) as the text editor
- `pip --version` → pip 20.0.2

Also this popped up once:

```
2020-03-16 22:32:47.640 python[32453:105648] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
```

(I searched in the Internet, but I *only* found [Tkinter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tkinter) cases, so I think this bug is related with window opening in Python?)

It restarts every single time when I execute the turtle program in Python. How do I fix this bug?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without it it might be impossible to find an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Turtle uses graphics. Maybe due to low graphic resolution, your machine is crashing.

1. Change your performance from low -to- high.
2. Change the power option from saving to performance.
3. Clear the background processes
4. Last, but not least, check your machine cooling, may this works.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to fix my Bug. I don't think it's the graphics problem, becuase it ran flawlessly in IDLE.